# why are animations inconsistent when using jquery animate() in chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, animation

I'm using jQuery (v2.1.1) `animate()` to transition a `height` property.

In FF 30 the animation is consistently smooth, but in Chrome 35/38 it's *instant* ~50% of the time.

I noticed that when this happens, jQuery animation "Timer Fired" events are clustered together in the dev tools Timeline (see image).

**Why is this happening and how can it be remedied?**

Note that according to the Timeline the animation stays below the 60fps threshold.

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code and possibly create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look into using  [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) instead of jQuery's `animate` function? This, I think, will give you better performance.

Also, instead of animating the `height` property, you should look into performing a [CSS scale transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). On modern browsers, this will pretty much guarantee the 60fps that you are looking for.

Here's a little jsFiddle to demonstrate how you can manipulate the scaleY property via CSS transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/XpD29/ (note: only tested this on Chrome 36)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I can't use a transform because the animation has to be within layout (eg, a treeview branch that pushes node elements down as it expands). I'll try the css transition, but it's a bit more work (eg, need to calc height and add/remove transitionend listener). Mainly I'm just curious 1) why it only works 50% of the time in Chrome (even though fps stays below 60 at all times), and 2) why FF manages to animate it with buttery smoothness 100% of the time.

Comment: Follow up: the css transition approach works much better than animate(), thanks! It's still janky compared to FF if there's many elements, but it should do.